# Vagrant machine increase in memory not work

Tags: memory, vagrant, out-of-memory, singularity-container

I'm trying to increase the size of my vagrant virtual machine allowing me to build singularity without much success... I searched on internet and applied scrupulously different config but nothing makes.
Here is my Vagrant file :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "sylabs/singularity-3.0-ubuntu-bionic64"

  ... (comment code)

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.memory = 2048
  v.cpus = 2
end
end
```

But unfortunately it remains on the basic configuration ...

Thanking you in advance for the time you can give me.

BoudSTER